# how to avoid getting email into spam

Tags: asp.net, email, webmail

I have develop a web application in asp.net in which i need to send the email for the communication which will work fine for few days. now a day my all emails getting into spam folder.

i use the following code to send mail

```
public  void SendMailMessage(string to, string subject, string body, AlternateView Altv, string bcc="")
        {
            // Instantiate a new instance of MailMessage
            MailMessage mMailMessage = new MailMessage();

            // Set the sender address of the mail message
            mMailMessage.From = new MailAddress("FORM EMAIL");
            // Set the recepient address of the mail message

            mMailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));

            mMailMessage.Subject = subject;
            // Set the body of the mail message

            if (bcc != "")
            {
                mMailMessage.Bcc.Add(bcc);
            }

            mMailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(Altv);

            mMailMessage.Body = body;

            // Set the format of the mail message body as HTML
            mMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            // Set the priority of the mail message to normal
            mMailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;



            // Instantiate a new instance of SmtpClient
            SmtpClient mSmtpClient = new SmtpClient();

            mSmtpClient.Host = "HOST";
            // Send the mail message

            mSmtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential()
            {
                UserName = "EMAIID",
                Password = "PASSWORD"

            };
            mSmtpClient.Port = 25;
            mSmtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            mSmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;  
            try
            {
                mSmtpClient.Send(mMailMessage);
            }
            catch
            {}

        }
```

I want to add the signed-by,reply-to,unsubscribe to email header so to get email into inbox and how to

Comment: Probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899298/aspx-send-mail-as-spam

Comment: I'm on a contract with a firm that sends marketing campaigns on behalf of other firms and I know the answer to your question is quite involved. There is nothing obviously wrong with your code and it is more likely to do with what you are sending, where you are sending it and how your domain/IPs are configured. Are you able to tell us the From address used? What about a sample of the kind of body being sent? Have you checked your mailing list for odd addresses, for example ones ending in @spamhaus.org? How many emails do you send per minute? Is the email transaction related or marketing?

Answer (score 0):

Add To your Code :

```
        mMailMessage.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
```

Kindly Refer this : [Avoiding Spam](http://www.andreas-kraus.net/blog/tips-for-avoiding-spam-filters-with-systemnetmail/)